# Resource identifier 'App.xaml' has already been used in this assembly in Xamarin [VS2017]

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I can build the solution but cannot run the solution via Live Player. 
This error happened after I create sub-folder in my project and move some XAML file into that folder. 
I've already Clean & Rebuilt, Manually delete /obj and /bin folders, and re-install Visual Studio and Xamarin. What should I do to solve this problem, please help. Thanks!

Full Error Log

> (1,1): error: Resource identifier 'App.xaml' has already been used in
>   this assembly (1,1): error: Resource identifier 'MainPage.xaml' has
>   already been used in this assembly (1,1): error: Dependent project
>   PDTHP.csproj failed to build, using old version.
>   ..Directory..(Project Name).Android\MainActivity.cs (1,1): error: The
>   type or namespace name 'App' could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?) Failed to debug your app.

Answer (score 0):

I've already solved the problem. I don't know the cause yet but it works now. Just uninstall Live Player in mobile phone and re-install + pair again.